# Require commutative operation in Rust trait bound

Tags: rust, traits, commutativity

Suppose I have a group of related non-scalar structs with a commutative arithmetic operation defined on them. For example,

```
struct Foo {
    a: f64,
    b: f64
}

impl Add<f64> for Foo {
    type Output = Foo;
    
    fn add(self, v: f64) -> Self::Output {
        Foo {
            a: self.a + v,
            b: self.b + v
        }
    }
}

impl Add<Foo> for f64 {
    type Output = Foo;
    
    fn add(self, foo: Foo) -> Self::Output {
        Foo {
            a: foo.a + self,
            b: foo.b + self
        }
    }
}
```

I want to implement a trait on this group of structs, taking advantage of this operation. That is, I want something like the following:

```
trait Bar: Add<f64, Output = Self> + Sized {
    fn right_add(self, f: f64) -> Self {
        self + f
    }
    
    // Doesn't compile!
    fn left_add(self, f: f64) -> Self {
        f + self
    }
}
```

However, this currently doesn't compile, since the super-trait bound doesn't include the left addition of `f64` to `Self`. My question is: **How can I state this commutative trait bound?**

([Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8da51a7076b029bb5f9d49a3640b191a).)

Edit: To be clear, I'm aware that `right_add` and `left_add` have the same output. I'm mainly interested in the ergonomics of not having to remember which is "correct" according to the compiler. In addition, I'm curious to learn how to do this, even if it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: well, in this case, there is no difference in letf and right. so `    
    fn left_add(self, f: f64) -> Self {
        self + f
    }`
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=af63bacac6dd90cd6999089a47efb2c9

Comment: Thanks. See edit for some clarification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inverted trait bounds like this are the exact usecase for `where` syntax:

```rust
trait Bar
where
    f64: Add<Self, Output = Self>,
    Self: Add<f64, Output = Self> + Sized,
{
    fn right_add(self, f: f64) -> Self {
        self + f
    }

    fn left_add(self, f: f64) -> Self {
        f + self
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c3392a56c2f2d938862ac07f038d20fa)

Comment: I didn't realise you could use the `where` clause to bound foreign types like `f64` in this way, but it makes sense. Thanks!